# Why UseSqlCe() support remove from the EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 on latest version?

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, version, sql-server-ce

```
optionsBuilder.UseSqlCe(@"Connectionstring");
```

// Package EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 2.2.0.7

> Error  CS1061  'DbContextOptionsBuilder' does not contain a definition for 'UseSqlCe' and no accessible extension method 'UseSqlCe' accepting a first argument of type 'DbContextOptionsBuilder' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Are you targeting .net framework? Do you have the correct using statement?

Comment: @ErikEJ I am targeting .NET core 5.0

Comment: @ErikEJ In EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServerCompact40 version 2.2.0.7 UseSqlCe() support does not exists.
Is there alternative way to use UseSqlCe()?

Answer (score 0):

The provider only supports .NET Framework.

You can sponsor an update from me, or use another database engine, like for example SQLite.